Troubleshooting AWS IoT Custom Authorizer: Resolving 403 Forbidden Error for MQTT and HTTPS Requests
I have a AWS IOT custom authorizer that I have configured using Tutorial: Creating a custom authorizer for AWS IoT Core - AWS IoT Core.
I am able to test invoke the authorizer and it works as expected. However when a device through mqtt, or if i use Postman and send a https request, I am getting a 403, Forbidden Message. Can someone help me set this up? The use case is to connect a third-party device on to my IOT mqtt network.
The postman response looks like this:
{
  "message": "Forbidden",
  "traceId": "d59a6c0d-4b55-8a82-0198-ea2300c5c609"
}

My Cloudwatch IOT Logs look like this:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-04-25 18:42:55.669",
    "logLevel": "INFO",
    "traceId": "95a9d3ed-cdf2-5090-ccbe-c57258e6d22d",
    "accountId": "***********",
    "status": "Success",
    "eventType": "Disconnect",
    "protocol": "MQTT",
    "clientId": "******************",
    "principalId": "***********************************",
    "sourceIp": "***.**.**.**",
    "sourcePort": 60634,
    "disconnectReason": "MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT"
}

From the cloud watch logs its clear, that the url hit my custom IOT endpoint, however it did not route the message to my lambda function to perform further authentication.
Also I have used the same signature, token name, and other details that i used when doing a test-invoke cli call to also perform a similar HTTPS call.
Thanks.
